# pandas- fetch_pandas_all Connector Kills Kernel

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm having trouble with the pandas connector for Snowflake.

The last line of this code causes the immediate death of the python kernel. Any suggestions on how to diagnose such a situation?

```
import pyarrow
import snowflake.connector
import pandas as pd

ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user=********,
    password=********,
    account=********,
    warehouse='compute_wh',
    database='SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA',
    schema='WEATHER'
)
query = 'select * from weather_14_total'
cs = ctx.cursor()
cs.execute()
cs.fetch_pandas_all()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was facing the same issue, by just follow few step issue solved.

If you are getting `_expected_pyarrow_version` in the stacktrace of the error. Follow these steps:

Step 1:

```py
pip uninstall pyarrow
```

Step 2:

```py
pip install pyarrow==6.0.0
```

Then run your program, again.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think you are confusing things a bit.

1. If you want to use pandas, [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-pandas.html) is the right link to follow. It's the Snowflake documentation.
2. You can also not use pandas if you want and just do it:

   cs = ctx.cursor()

   try:

   ```
    cs.execute("SELECT col1, col2 FROM test_table ORDER BY col1")
    for (col1, col2) in cs:
        print('{0}, {1}'.format(col1, col2))
   ```

   finally:

   ```
    cs.close()
   ```

   OR:

   cs = ctx.cursor()

   query = "Select * from table"

   try:

   ```
    cs.execute(query)
    .....
    .....
   ```

   finally:

   ```
    cs.close()
   ```

Also, the documentation link is [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html).